# Is it possible yet to make a single page web page without using server side such as PHP?

Tags: php, html, javascript, asp.net

I'm looking to make a simple web page (mainly used on the local machine) that would just be a single file (such as htm or html) but would dynamically change based on the url.

For example, if I went to '**file:///C:/Sandbox/test.htm**' it might display the following...

> Hello World

But if I went to '**file:///C:/Sandbox/test.htm?page=2**' it might display the following...

> You are visiting my second page!

I know I can do this type of thing with PHP or ASP but is it possible to do it with HTML or javascript or anything "native" to the browser yet?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: How in the world this is considered to be more of a programming development question rather than a website development question is beyond me...  I don't get why someone would have felt the need to move it from the webmasters exchange to the stackoverflow exchange...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Client side javascript can know about the query string on a URL.  In javascript, it can be accessed through `location.search`.

You could have your javscript show and hide different sections of the page based on the information in the query string.

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for.  Combine location.search with a few hidden div's and then using (none or inline) document.getElementById("page_name").style["display"] = "inline"; worked out great!